# how to install phpUnittest?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, phpunit

I am trying to write a Unit Test to test my YII application using phpunitest. I installed it and when I try to run my test I use shell command:

```
phpunit --bootstrap bootstrap.php DbTest.php
```

then I get this error:

```
PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Cannot open file "bootstrap.php".
```

how Can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be easily fixed.)

You should write correct path to your bootstrap.php. That's all.)

You can run `phpunit --bootstrap boostrap.php SMTest.php` only if your boostrap.php lies in same directory that SMTest.php.

Or you can write absolute paths:

`phpunit --bootstrap /www/tests/config/boostrap.php /www/tests/unit/SMTest.php`

and invoke this command from any place.

Answer (score 0):

your bootstrap goes in your phpunit.xml config file.

So it would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php" colors="true">
</phpunit>
```

and when you run your test you run it with

```
phpunit --configuration=phpunit.xml
```

For reference: The [phpunit.xml config section](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) in the manual.